# Highlight Indentation in Visual Studio IDE 2005

Tags: visual-studio, indentation

I want to HighLight Indentation in Visual Studio IDE 2005.

I want to replace space with periods(.)

for e.g:- This is what I want

```
main
.{
..Print("hello World");
.}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only built in thing that's similar is Edit|Advanced|View Whitespace (Ctrl-E, S)

CodeRush Express, a free download also does stuff in this direction (though it might not work in 2005?)